# April Fool's Enigma

Tags: visual, steganography, unsolved-mysteries

Every year, a famous French youtuber (e-penser) presents his enigma of April Fool, but this year, targeting specifically a group of people who have done particularly well last year, he raised the difficulty. Maybe too much. We are about fifty people on discord to seek every day but we do not advance any more. So I share this enigma to see if we are the only ones to be able to draw anything from it.

Here is the list of proven things:

- The image has only two colors, black and white
- The image measures 7000x600px and the fact that it gives us 42 is intentional
- The image is called "avril.gif", but that does not mean anything.
- Metadatas are useless

Any help and advancement would be of great help to us.

[image: The enigma]

Comment: Do you have any information about what _sort_ of thing you're looking for? What sort of thing has it been in the past?

Comment: We don't have any information about what we're looking for, that's our biggest problem, he refuse to tell us anything about the enigma. In the past, enigmas were a list of youtube videos to follow in the right order to find the end and last year we used steganography on a video to find an url and a password.

Comment: The coordinates of the lines, the obvious ones, and the not obvious ones, might be useful.

Comment: It somehow gives me a musical impression. Can't say why, though.

Comment: Given that the lines look like they're laying out X and Y coords in some fashion, the coordinates of the corners of the shape might also be useful.  Given the way that white-to-black overlay seems to be a Thing for this, it might be better to pull those in as two rectangles.

Comment: Also, I guess this is the same thing as http://boards.4channel.org/sci/thread/10515522/crack-this - which appears to be the original form of the puzzle.

Comment: We already have the coordinates of the lines and the rectangles but we don't know what to do with them. And the 4chan thread was posted by a friend who also works on this enigma

Comment: @Brandon_J Maybe. The OP gives the impression that the question here is being asked on behalf of _everyone_ who's trying to solve it; if that's the case then I think the obvious problem with ongoing contests doesn't really arise.

Comment: Wait, is the story surrounding this puzzle actually *real* or just made-up to add to the quality of the puzzle?

Comment: Yes the story is real and Gareth is right : there's no contest, we all tried to solve this together

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt interesting... :P

Comment: While I'm at it with the links, here's the [twitter update by e-penser](https://twitter.com/epenser/status/1112678237417754624) with some discussion. Pity I don't know a bit of French :( If you have any updates, let us know! This looks like a lot of fun.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the link, I should have thought of it. And you can also find the discord link in the answers and a Google Doc link in the dedicated channel on discord, which is where we all discuss about the enigma, for those who understand French. But, to be honest, we didn't make significant progress.

Comment: There's a Chinese method of doing large number multiplication that involves counting the intersecting lines and this looks exactly like that to me. Just a thought. That would equate to 1,316 x 31,411,911 = 41,338,074,876

Comment: I apparently wasn't seeing the entire screen and the last set of lines is 11 long.. kind of shoots that idea down.